# Automatic Oracle partitioning by month in the tablespace corresponding to the month

Tags: oracle, partition

I need to partition my table by month automatically and that each partition is in the tablespace corresponding to the month. I don't need the round robin way. I want each partition to be in its tablespace. Thanks

Comment: I think because you have to use the round Robin way, because Oracle can automatically create partitions but Oracle cannot create automatically tablespaces.

Comment: Thanks. I created the tablespaces for every month and I use store in, but I don't want the way round robin. I would like other way to match each tablespace with exact month partition

Answer (score 2):

As I already stated, you have to use round robin, because the tablespaces have to exist at desing time. Otherwise Oracle cannot create partitions automatically. Would be this:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
  START_TIME  TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,
  more columns
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (START_TIME) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
STORE IN (
    TS_JAN, TS_FEB, TS_MAR,
    TS_APR, TS_MAY, TS_JUN,
    TS_JUL, TS_AUG, TS_SEP,
    TS_OKT, TS_NOV, TS_DEC
)
(
  PARTITION P_INITIAL VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:00') TABLESPACE TS_JAN
);
```

Just ensure timestamp of the inital partition (e.g. 1st of January) matches the correct tablespace.

Otherwise you have to create all partitions and tablespaces manually in advance.

Comment: Yes, that example is the same I have in my DB, but I have the little problem that I wrote before. Thank you very much for your help.